# Pandas concat 2 data frames with different columns: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: pandas

I've seen this question before but I see it for duplicate columns, my columns are different:

```
df.cols: Index(['keys', 'clicks', 'impressions', 'ctr', 'position'], dtype='object')
split_df.cols: Index(['DEVICE', 'DATE', 'QUERY', 'COUNTRY', 'PAGE'], dtype='object')
```

the `split_df` dataframe is actually from the original `df`, the `keys` column from df was a list and I split out each element into several new columns (see below) which then became `split_df`. Now I'm just trying to concat them back together but I see when I concat

> Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

```
    df = g_conn.get_search_console(ds)

split_df = pd.DataFrame(df['keys'].tolist(), columns=['DEVICE', 'DATE', 'QUERY', 'COUNTRY', 'PAGE'])


df = pd.concat([df, split_df], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the duplicates are in your row index(es) not columns.  Rows not columns  because `axis=1`.

For example this causes that error:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('ABCD')}, index=list('1122'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': list('WXYZ')}, index=list('3455'))

pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects